# cout and cin repeating within a function in C++?

Tags: c++, cout, cin

The validatePlay function I've written is supposed to accept an entered character that matches a play type.

```
char validatePlay();

void getHandPlayed(char);


int main()
{

    char play= validatePlay();

    validatePlay();

    getHandPlayed(play);

    system("pause");
}

char validatePlay()
{
    char play;
    cout << "enter play (R)ock, (P)aper or (S)cissor ";
    cin >> play;
    while (cin.fail() || play != 'R' && play != 'P' && play != 'S')
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(80, '\n');
        cout << "re-enter play (R)ock, (P)aper or (S)cissor ";
        cin >> play;
    }
    return play;

}

void getHandPlayed(char play)
{

    switch(play)
    {
        case 'R':
            cout << "Rock"<<endl;
            break; 
        case 'P':
            cout << "Paper"<<endl;
            break;
        case 'S':
            cout << "Scissors"<<endl;
            break;

    }
}
```

It sort of works, but for some reason, the cout and cin appear twice no matter what I enter but it's only taking in the first char I enter. It ends up looking like this.

enter play (R)ock, (P)aper or (S)cissor S

enter play (R)ock, (P)aper or (S)cissor R

Scissors

Press any key to continue . . .

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: you call validatePlay twice. The second time you ignore what it returns i.e. the read value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call validatePlay() twice.

The first time is here:

```
char play= validatePlay();
```

The second time is here:

```
validatePlay();
```

You are only storing and using the result from the first call.

Answer (score 0):

You have this in your main:

```
char play= validatePlay();

validatePlay();
```

What do you think that does?